# If I use WUBI to install Ubuntu, can I use Windows Control panel to uninstall it if I don't like it?

Tags: wubi

Dell Vostro 200
Windows XP service pack 3, 32 bit
Intel Core 2 duo
CPU @ 2.4 Ghz
RAM 2037 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Since WUBI installs just like a windows application, it can be UN-installated like one.  Keep in mind that after Ubuntu 12.10 WUBI has been dropped.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch.  I appreciate your expertise and quick response.  I won't use any version beyond 12.10 for my trial of Ubuntu. Sadly, I lack the 15 level reputation to vote your answer up.